# In tomcat, how does an http request body get transformed into an java InputStream via jax-rs Jersey?

Tags: java, tomcat, jersey

I am researching how video uploads work through http requests. Consider the case where we are trying to upload a file with a single http request (it's a small file) by passing it as the body of the request.
For the purpose of the question, let's assume we are uploading to a tomcat server implemented in Java with Jersey as our Jaxrs framework.
Suppose we have a Jersey resource that consumes an octet stream (our file) in the form an java InputStream argument to the jersey resource method.

I am trying to understand how the body of the http request (which is presumably the file itself) gets transformed into a Java InputStream fed into the Jersey resource method.

I have looked here
https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/http.html to try to get a better understanding of the tomcat http connector and how it processes http requests.

I have looked here https://jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/index.html to try to get a sense of how jersey might be converting input it gets from tomcat.

However there are some basic questions I still haven't been able to answer.

1. When a video download is initiated, does the InputStream that Jersey is consuming point back to the http request body, or has the file already been uploaded to tomcat and is the InputStream only pointing to some temp file somewhere on the tomcat server?

Is the http request paused until the server actually starts reading from the InputStream?

2. If the InputStream is pointing to the http request body, what is it actually pointing to? It's fairly intuitive to understand what the InputStream is pointing to when reading a file from disk, but what is the equivalent for an http request?

I apologize for asking these basic questions, but I haven't been able to find a good reference for these questions through my personal research.
If anybody could point me to a reference, that would be very helpful.

Comment: Is this an academic question? Meaning, you are just curious as to how the bits get from one place to another? Or are you more asking about how to *use* Tomcat/Jersey/JAXRS?

Comment: @ChristopherSchultz Both. I believe I need to understand exactly how the bits are transferred from client to server in order to avoid making incorrect assumptions when using Jersey and Tomcat.

Comment: I haven't traced through the code for Jersey, but Tomcat is pretty transparent when it comes to delivering the data to an application (which would be Jersey in this case). I'm assuming that, ignoring possibly several wrappers of varying descriptions, the `InputStream` you get in your Jersey service is essentially reading directly from the `HttpServletRequest`, which is about as close to the wire as you are going to get. There should be no buffering unless Jersey is treating the request as a "file upload", which behaves differently as per the Servlet Spec.

Comment: @ChristopherSchultz thanks for the insight.